# we are getting non readable responses while recording siebel 8.1 application using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

iam not getting proper responses while recording sibel 8.1 application using jmeter.iam getting below non readable responses
"�X�n�6��`�#�Qז�7[�Z�i=�i`�(�i���H�FRv�a��ؓ퐔d�I��+���\��C*�H%1�"���HQ����R<�ڱQL�
�Y�Κ�DvLY'��A�ľ#�F#B�3�@�T��M�7�w��-���"���7t���|¾Jؚ����,E�H������i]��~���-"���2��H�� �x�GA����kpPL�*����9L)z��s�Ύ�*2���T���������� &��l��7躩�)�Ѐ���δ�n�B������I}��ϲ8n��hgʨ:8!MQ��1Rx�����sЊ��c@�8�aH٦��E�t��)"����?̅��TH5�q��"����
�� �
ʁ{�G�3����L���7f�֚`-����N��z���T�'�\`�}�f`����
]k�2����մv�u]�nC�qfm��>��A��`-�+�O�z/^�i��8�9��ŧ/z�KJy5�@V!��M�W�ٳEXE��~��Wiz�+`a�"
due to this i cant correlate my script
1.iam came to know that if we  remove accept encoding from all samplers(after recording) proper responses can be achieved but i want proper responses while recording only

Comment: For analyzing requests/response you can also use Fiddler (windows) or charles (mac). You can also try Blazemter chrome plugin for script recording.

Comment: Hi arif sibel 8.1 application works with onlyIE  versions

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Accept-Encoding” – gzip, deflate` line from the [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) - you'll be able to see the uncompressed data.

Also [Unable to Correlation in Siebel Web-http](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-Correlation-in-Siebel-Web-http-td529788.html) thread might be helpful.

Comment: Hi Dimitri i want to disable gzip while recording only,rerunning the script is fine by removing accept encoding due to this i cant correlate. Thanks in advance

Comment: from the above link i came to know to disable gzip compression n browsers ,here i want to disable for internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to what seems to be a buggy compressed stream served by Siebel as per:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1869
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1877

Still this has been workaround in JMeter > 4.0 in:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61058

As of March 2018, you can try nightly build (after 6 march 2018) of jmeter :

- https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/

You'll need to set in user.properties the below property then restart JMeter and start recording:

> httpclient4.deflate_relax_mode=true